# Question about set theory class notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory (say, ZF) the 'class notation' is introduced. In general one could say that a class is something of the form $\{ x \, | \, \varphi ( x ) \}$ where $\varphi ( x)$ is some formula in the language of set theory, having only $x$ as free variable.

I know that these (i.e. classes) are just a matter of handy notation, and that in principle they can always 'deleted', so they're not really part of the language.

Now I've heard that the big difference between *sets* on the one hand, and *classes* on the other hand, is that sets can be element of other sets while classes cannot be element of a set (and also, classes cannot be element of another class). I thought I understood this, however I have the following concern. I will give a concrete example below.

Let $A=\{ x \, | \, \varphi ( x ) \}$ be a class, and let $B$ be the class $\{ x \, | \, \emptyset \in x, \mbox{ and if } y \in x \mbox{ then } \{ y \} \in x \}$. Now, the expression "$A \in B$" *does* make sense, in this particular case, I think. Namely it would be simply an abbreviation of the sentence $\emptyset \in A \wedge \forall y \, ( y \in A \rightarrow \{ y \} \in A )$. And this means that $\varphi ( \emptyset ) \wedge \forall y \, ( \varphi ( y ) \rightarrow \varphi ( \{ y \} ) )$. (Note that in this example the 'a priori' class $B$ in fact happens to be a set itself, assuming some axioms.)

So my point is: it seems to be the case that in some cases it *would* make sense. (Of course, the reason why it makes sense in this particular example is because in the sentence "$\emptyset \in x, \mbox{ and if } y \in x \mbox{ then } \{ y \} \in x$" defining the class $B$, there are only terms of the form $\ldots \in x$, and not the other way around; if for example there would have appeared $x \in \emptyset$ we would finally get $A \in \emptyset$ which doesn't make any sense.)

Thus, I think that *in general* it does not make sense to write things like "$A \in B$" where $A$ and $B$ are classes.

But I'm a bit in doubt about all of this, as it seems pretty confusing. Hence,

**Questions:**

1) What I have described above, does that make sense? Is my 'analysis' correct? Or is what I've said essentially false.

2) In cases when $A \in B$ (with $A,B$ classes) does make sense, can we just write it like this? Or maybe write it along with a comment that in this particular case it makes sense, as it is just an abbreviation of this and that formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we write $A\in B$, we invariably require that $A$ is an object of the universe, which means that we require it to be a set. But remember that sets are themselves classes.

Your example can be seen as a "complication" of the following example:
$$\{x\mid x=x\}\in\{\{x\mid x=x\}\}$$

But this statement means that $B$ is not even a class. It is a $2$-class, or a conglomerate. If we want $B$ to be a class them its elements must be sets.

So while it may make some sense to apply $A\in B$ for proper classes sometimes, we don't want to have a convention which is too confusing. So classes which are elements of other classes have to be sets.

Comment: Well I don't really see why my example is 'similar' to yours. You perform a set-theoretic operation on a class. I.e. your right-hand side (namely $\{ \{ x \, | \, x = x \} \}$) doesn't even make sense. In my example both $A$ and $B$ make perfectly sense. But I guess I understand your main point. You say "classes which are elements of other classes have to be sets". If I understand correctly, this is a (notational) *convention* right?